# java.lang.SecurityException: Requesting code from com.android.providers.downloads to be run in process my.package

Tags: java, android, listadapter, android-handler, android-download-manager

The error appears in RecyclerView Adapter on different versions of android and devices. 
Im retrieving information about download progress every second and show percents on item layout.

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ItemViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Download item = downloads.get(position);
    holder.titleTv.setText(downloads.get(position).getTitle());
    Cursor cursor = downloadManager.query(
            new DownloadManager.Query().setFilterById(item.getDownloadId()));

    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToNext()) {
        int status = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS));
        if (status == DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING
                || status == DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING)
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Cursor c = downloadManager.query(
                            new DownloadManager.Query()
                                    .setFilterById(item.getDownloadId()));
                    float percent = 100;
                    if (c != null) {
                        if (c.moveToNext()) {
                            int downloadedBytes = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(
                                    DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR)
                            );
                            int totalBytes = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(
                                    DownloadManager.COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES)
                            );

                            percent = totalBytes == 0 ? 0 : downloadedBytes / (float) (totalBytes / 100);

                            holder.percentTv.setText(String.valueOf(Math.round(percent)).concat("%"));
                            holder.progressLayout.setCurrentProgress(Math.round(percent));
                        }
                        c.close();
                    }
                    if (percent != 100)
                        holder.progressHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                }
            }.run();
        else {
            if (status == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL) {
                holder.percentTv.setText("100%");
                holder.progressLayout.setCurrentProgress(100);
            } if (status == DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED)
                holder.percentTv.setText("Failed");
            else
                holder.progressLayout.setCurrentProgress(100);
            if (!Utils.isFileExists(item.getFilepath()))
                item.delete();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is crash log

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: Requesting code from com.android.providers.downloads (with uid 10026) to be run in process my.package (with uid 10134)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.getPackageInfo(ActivityThread.java:1877)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.getPackageInfo(ActivityThread.java:1853)
   at android.app.ContextImpl.createPackageContextAsUser(ContextImpl.java:2231)
   at android.app.ContextImpl.createPackageContext(ContextImpl.java:2217)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4977)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:4657)
   at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2494)
   at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1110)
   at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:365)
   at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:324)
   at android.app.DownloadManager$Query.runQuery(DownloadManager.java:1262)
   at android.app.DownloadManager.query(DownloadManager.java:1473)
   at my.package.adapters.DownloadsAdapter$1.run(DownloadsAdapter.java:71)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5302)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Can't figure out whats the crash is, and how to reproduce that crash.
Hope to your help stackoverflow community.

Comment: Hi,
Did you get the reason behind this crash or exception?
I am facing the same but for a different content provider.

Is it due to a permission thing?

Comment: @NikhilKumar Sorry, but no